# Adding SwitchCompat programmatically error

Tags: java, android, layout

I'm trying to add `android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat` programmatically and I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.lang.CharSequence.length()' on a null object reference
at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:422)
at android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat.makeLayout(SwitchCompat.java:602)
at android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat.onMeasure(SwitchCompat.java:526)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1458)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:746)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1458)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:746)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.measureChildCollapseMargins(Toolbar.java:1218)
at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onMeasure(Toolbar.java:1326)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1458)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:746)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.onMeasure(AppBarLayout.java:199)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$Behavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:888)
at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$Behavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:652)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1458)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:746)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1458)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:746)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2899)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2108)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1224)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1115)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6023)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Chore
```

but when I'm using `Switch` everything is ok. why is this happening? this is my code:

```
SwitchCompat switchBox = (SwitchCompat) LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.checkbox, null);
switchBox.setId(i);
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "iransansfont.ttf");
switchBox.setText(convert_num((nodesModelArrayList.get(i).type ? "بیمارستان " : "مطب ") + nodesModelArrayList.get(i).node_name + ": " + nodesModelArrayList.get(i).stat));
switchBox.setTypeface(typeface);
switchBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangeListener);
linearLayout.addView(switchBox);
switchBox.setChecked(true);
```

Comment: Please provide the complete stack trace.

Comment: i've edited my post @MikeM.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use an activity context and not application context for inflating views so that e.g. themes work.

The crash is because the `textOn` and `textOff` labels are null that would normally get their default values from a theme.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue trying to create the SwitchCompat like this:

```
SwitchCompat switchCompat = new SwitchCompat(getContext());
switchCompat.setText(...);
```

Fixed it by inflating it as an XML layout:

```
layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_switch_compat, parent, false);
```

And view_switch_compat.xml contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/switchCompat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Hope it helps someone :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a custom SwitchMaterial.

The problem was that I used 0 as the style by default.

Changing it to `com.google.android.material.R.attr.switchStyle` solved the problem.

```
class MySwitchMaterial @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = com.google.android.material.R.attr.switchStyle,
) : SwitchMaterial(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
```